# Chrome Extension communicate with rest web service

Tags: javascript, web-services, google-chrome-extension

I am new in chrome extension, and I am developing an extension that will communicate to my rest web service. My rest web service will return a json string. What i wanted to do is to call my web service, get the response json.

Currently I have this in my background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
        var link = tab.url;
        alert(link);
    });
});
```

My plan is when user clicked on the icon extension, the current tab url will be sent to my web service, and it will get response json.

My question is, what is the code or syntax that does something like `webclient.downloadstring` in C#? Or how can I communicate with the web service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The API you're looking for is called `XMLHttpRequest` (also known as "AJAX"). Read the documentation at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr for more information.

Here's an example:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
    var link = tab.url;
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', 'http://example.com/?whatever=' + link);
    x.onload = function() {
        alert(x.responseText);
    };
    x.send();
});
```

Note. The `XMLHttpRequest` API is asynchronous. This means that you cannot do something like this:

```js
...
var result;
x.onload = function() {
    result = x.responseText;
};
x.send();
alert(result); // Does not behave as you expect!
```

Comment: I tried the code but it seems there is no response. I expect the alert message  should pop up (though i replaced with a string message) but does not.

Comment: What permission was that?

Answer (score 0):

I think all thing is in permissions.

http://www.appuntivari.net/informatica/programmazione/chrome-extension/chrome-extension-with-restfull-external-api

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "AppuntiVari.net - Agenda events",
  "description": "AppuntiVari.net - Agenda events",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://appuntivari.net/*"],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "homepage_url": "http://appuntivari.net",

  "background": { "scripts": ["js/jquery-1.10.2.js",
"js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js","background.js","popup.js"] },

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "48.png"
  ],
  "icons": {"16": "16.png", "48": "48.png", "128": "128.png"}
}
```

```
$.ajax({
url:  "http://appuntivari.net/MyServiceAPI-portlet/
api/secure/jsonws/agenda/get-events-byIdUser/id_user/"+id_user,
type: "GET",
```

Comment: Add I see that the it deals with CORS rights (HTTP header) in your remote server. It must give appropiate rights to all clients, and your Chrome extension too. It's common to all AJAX connections in browsers.